# git shows there are no changes after doing `add -u`

Tags: git

Git showed that there were modified files not prepared for commit but after doing: `git add -u` , `git status` no longer shows any changes in those files. What could be wrong ?

Comment: Please add your terminal window commands and results.

Comment: "no longer shows any changes in those files".. are you talking about the output of `git diff`?

Comment: git status does not show the files added to the working tree

Answer (score 1):

Since the `git add -u` only add modified/removed files, check how those file are listed by git status.

If they are untracked, they would not be added by `git add -u`, only `git add`.

Comment: they were tracked. Is it possible that if there were really no modifications in the files then `git add -u` figured that out and therefore it stopped showing that ?

Comment: @CaptainJacksparrow Yes, it depends on the nature of the diff: what does git diff returns? they could be part of a submodule.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you had changes that you had reverted in your worktree.

For example:

```
$ echo A >foo.txt
$ git commit -a -m "some commit"
[master 74c7015] some commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

At this point, a commit is created with `foo.txt` containing "A".

```
$ echo B >foo.txt 
$ git add foo.txt
```

Now, the index has content "B" for `foo.txt`.

```
$ echo A >foo.txt
```

And now, the worktree has content "A" again for `foo.txt`, but the index still has "B":

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   foo.txt

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   foo.txt
```

If one runs `git add -u`, then the index will be updated with the content of the worktree, i.e. "A" for `foo.txt`, which matches the content in `HEAD`:

```
$ git add -uv
add 'foo.txt'
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```